# Iterating for each value of area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive comparator made of *6* columns. On mobile devices, this comparator switches to a tabbed panel, and i want only **the first** column to be displayed by adding a class `.display-none` to the others.

Each column of this comparator has a class like `.column-1`, `.column-2`…

I tried the following code without success (`.display-none` class is not added to all wanted items) :

```
// calling the function on mobile devices
function hideColumns(){
    var y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; // column number I want to hide
    $('.column-' + y).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('display-none');
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to hide certain elements based on the screen size? If so use CSS media queries, not JS. If, for whatever reason, you did want to do this in JS, put a common class on the relevant elements and call `hide()` on them.

Comment: I dont not want to use media queries because I need to display the appropriate column when clicking on tabs. Here is the prototype : http://boukarabila.com/alta/comparator/index.html

Comment: Try to console `$(this)` to confirm it's pointing to the DOM element you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over the list of numbers you have assigned to `y` variable. You need to do that. Current code gives something is not what you want...

```
var y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; 
'.column-' + y // ".column-2,3,4,5,6"
```

So basically here you are finding a dom element having a class `"column-2,3,4,5,6"`. Here is what things went wrong for you. Rather you do it like

```
function hideColumns() {
    var classes = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(num => `.column-${num}`).join(', ');

    $(classes).addClass('display-none');
}
```

## A Demo:

```js
function hideColumns() {
  var classes = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(num => `.column-${num}`).join(', ');
  $(classes).addClass('display-none');
}

$('.start').on('click', hideColumns);
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-1">1</div>
<div class="column-2">2</div>
<div class="column-3">3</div>
<div class="column-11">11</div>
<div class="column-4">4</div>
<div class="column-5">5</div>
<div class="column-15">15</div>
<div class="column-6">6</div>

<button class="start">
Play the Demo
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function and code seems okay, so the error could be in three places.

**First case**, the class of the column is not right `column-1` (or 2,3,4) does not exist.

You could check that with `console.log($(this))` inside the `.each()`

**Second case**,  you are never calling the function.

You could check that with `console.log('check')` inside the `hideColumns()` function

**Last case,** `var Y` is not a `number` but an `array` as the code in the example, then you must iterate first the array:

```
for (let number in y) {
 $('.column-' + y).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('display-none');
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is working or me :

```
function hideColumns(){
    var colArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(function(number){
        return ('.column-' + number);
    }).join(', ');
    $(colArray).each (function(){
        $(this).addClass('d-none');
    });
};
```